# jsession id is getting killed while getting redirected

Tags: oracle-ucm, oracle-access-manager

I have an application from where when I am clicking on a particular link, it taking me to me Oracle Universal Content Manager. As soon as I am in UCM if go back to my application it gets timed out(logging out).
While investigating I found that jsessiond id of my application is getting killed and new jsession id is getting generated.

Does anybody has any idea of how to retain this jsession or increasing the number of jsession id at UCM side?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sharmistha.

Answer (score 1):

```
    After searching on support side I got to know that :
    OAM protecting multiple WebLogic applications that are not sharing a session. The JSESSIONID cookie issued when a user accesses a second application will blow away the JSESSIONID from the first application.

    Now, what you usually see in such a setup is that the user can go back and access the first application without having to login again. However, underneath the covers they will be issued a new session. So, upon returning to the first application, any data associated with their original session will be lost and the application flow may be disrupted or different from the expected behavior.

    There are 3 ways doing this : 

        1.  Enable session sharing between your WLS applications.
        2.  Configure distinct WLS session cookie names (instead of JSESSIONID) for each application so that they won’t override each other.
        3.  Configure distinct cookie paths for each application (by default the JSESSIONID created by WLS has a path of “/”) so that they won’t override each other.

    I used second option: 

Step 1 : Unzipped the cs.ear file
Step 2 : Open web.xml file.
         a. Modify the filter entry for JpsFilter and add the following <init-parameter> entry at the end of this entry:
        <init-param>
                       <param-name>IdcSessionKey</param-name>
                       <param-value>YOURJSESSIONID</param-value>
          </init-param>
        b. Modify the filter entry for IdcFilter and the following entry at the end of this entry:
        <init-param>
                       <param-name>IdcSessionKey</param-name>
                       <param-value>YOURJSESSIONID</param-value>
        </init-param>
       c. Modify the servlet entry for adfAuthentication and add the following entry at the end of this entry:
        <init-param>
                       <param-name>IdcSessionKey</param-name>
                       <param-value>YOURJSESSIONID</param-value>
        </init-param>
Step 3: Open weblogic.xml.Add the following entry inside the <session-descriptor> entry:
            <cookie-name>YOURJSESSIONID</cookie-name>

Step 4: Re-generate cs.war and then cs.ear file.
Step 5: Copy the newly created ear file to your location. 
Step 6: Delete temp and cache wcm server domain. Then restart ucm server
```